# Permission error when setting global-acls in dovecot

Tags: permissions, dovecot, file-permissions, access-control-list

Dovecot's ACL plugin [instructions](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/acl/#global-acls) indicate that for global acl's, we're supposed to create an acl file in `/etc/dovecot/.` and to include the access control list items in it. So I've created `/etc/dovecot/global-acls` and included...

```
inbox.Archive owner lrwstipeka
inbox.Drafts owner lrwstipeka
inbox.Sent owner lrwstipeka
inbox.Junk owner lrwstipeka
inbox.Trash owner lrwstipeka
```

... which is supposed to prevent users from deleting these *system* folders.

This file is then loaded from the `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-acl.conf` plugin...

```
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins acl imap_acl
}

plugin {
  acl = vfile:/etc/dovecot/global-acls:cache_secs=300
}

plugin {
  acl_shared_dict = file:/path/to/mailbox/root/shared-mailboxes
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting the following errors in my syslog now showing that there's a permission issue with that file (or possibly with `stat()`, I'm not sure).

```
Error: acl vfile: stat(/etc/dovecot/global-acls) failed: Permission denied
Fatal: acl: backend vfile init failed with data: /etc/dovecot/global-acls:cache_secs=300
```

```
drw-rw----.   3 vmail dovecot  4096 Jan 26 13:37 .
drwxr-xr-x. 126 root  root    12288 Jan 26 16:52 ..
drw-rw----.   2 vmail dovecot  4096 Jan 25 15:46 conf.d
-rw-rw----.   1 vmail dovecot   535 Jan 26 20:17 dovecot.conf
-rw-rw----.   1 vmail dovecot   257 Jan 26 13:35 global-acls
```

As you can see, the permissions are set the same as the other files in `/etc/dovecot`. I've searched for hours for related errors, but I'm at a loss.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have no execute permission on the `/etc/dovecot` directory, it probably requires it.

Comment: @Bib I had always thought of /etc/ as just settings and such, didn't realize anything in there needed the execute bit, but now that I look, there's lots of directories in there with it. This seems to have done the trick! Appreciate the help, feel free to add the answer if you like, otherwise I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though dovecot is just reading a file under `/etc/dovecot`, it still requires the execute permission to be set on that directory.